# Elasticsearch - Avoid Word based and fuzzy based match when Phrase is matched

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query which searches on phrase, word level and fuzziness of words searched for. 
Is there a method where in I can restrict word and fuzzy matches when exact phrase is matched? 
Query developed is :

```
PUT test/_doc/1
{
  "field1": "this is a test query - query",
  "field2": "best rest vest pest"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "this is a test query",
            "type": "phrase",
            "slop": "2",
            "fields": []
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "this is a test query",
            "analyzer": "whitespace",
            "fields": []
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "this is a test query",
            "analyzer": "whitespace",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "fields": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "type": "unified",
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The result(only Highlight) obtained is :

"field1": [ "*this* *is* *a* *test* *query* - *query*" ], "field2": [ "*best* *rest* *vest* *pest*" ]

I don't want "best", "rest" , "vest" and "pest" to be highlighted when "this is a test query" phrase is matched

Answer (score 0):

Put your phrase search in a `must` and keep the other two conditions in the `should`. The query planner should be clever enough to figure this out for you.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of it?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example with say 3 documents and what you want to match and don't want to match? I'm not sure how "restrict word and fuzzy matches when exact phrase is matched" is supposed to work out exactly since the phrase match is the strictest one; once that matches the other 2 will just increase the score.

Comment: Hi @xeraa, Thanks for the reply.   I have indexed two documents  {
"field1":"this is a test query - query",
"field2":"best  rest vest pest"

}

Comment: This is my query and the highlight is :"field1": [
                        "<em>this</em> <em>is</em> <em>a</em> <em>test</em> <em>query</em> - <em>query</em>"
                    ],
                    "field2": [
                        "<em>best</em>  <em>rest</em> <em>vest</em> <em>pest</em>"
                    ]    I don't want "best", "rest" , "vest" and "pest" to be highlighted when "this is a test query" phrase is matched

Comment: I've added your example to the original question. Please describe what you are expecting to be different in your query. I assume putting the first should into a match is not sufficient?

Comment: As in the above example, i..e, when queried upon "this is a test query", Since the exact phrase "this is a test query" is matched in field 1, it should not match the following  1. the word "query" found separately in "field1". this is obtained through second part of the should query 2. words like "best", "rest", "vest", "pest" present in "field2" should not be matched. Only when the exact phrase is not matched , search should be on word based match or fuzzy match.

Comment: This is not how this works. The general idea of search is that something is more relevant if you have more matches, so everything is evaluated. I don't know of any method to stop after the first match from the top of my head; IMO not even `query_string` with `OR` works like that. Why would you want that behavior?